# cloudfront cdn download files as zip c#

Tags: c#, dotnetzip

I need to download images from my CDN server, not from my web server.

So is there any way to download images as ZIP from CDN server

EX. http://testcreative.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Test-Logo-Small-Black-transparent-1.png
I can't use server memory for processing as file size are high.

**Is there any way so i can just provide CDN url and ZIP will create on fly ?**

Comment: You must set the context where you are doing that, but store ni a temporal folder could be a solution.

Comment: i have found same soultion http://www.aspforums.net/Threads/211857/Download-multiple-files-as-Zip-
Archive-File-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet/ 
But here it is using memoru stream.

Comment: You always need some memory to manage the content while is processed, but I think that dotnetzip must have some Stream or Property like an autoflush to reduce it.